# WP jspPane Width Bug

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I installed plugin called "WP jScrollPane" on my wordpress. When I make width of the div 1140px, as you see on the image width of the pane becomes 124px. How can I fix this issue ?

screenshot: http://s16.postimage.org/694o99qnp/jsppane.jpg

Live: http://goo.gl/Vg9dx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace glutter values v-h (width-height) with 0

Comment: Thank you !! Solved the problem !